# App is published on Google Play, but can't be found via search

Tags: android, google-play

Recently published an app on Google Play. I can see that my app is released on Google Play when navigating via the URL (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=appID), but it's not found when I simply search for it.

What could be the reason that I don't find my app by search?

Answer (score 1):

As you said, it's recent. There is a chance that Play Store is still indexing it, so you will need to wait some time (I think 24 hours is a secure range).

Answer (score 1):

With new apps being published every day and ongoing changes to how **search** results are ranked, you can expect search results to change regularly.

Also, people can get different search results depending on their device, location, mobile carrier, support for available features, and more.

So you can expect it within a few days after play store crawl the data that they use for searching. (Personal experience 3 days)

More info you can find [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9042516?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks! Now that it's 4-days passed when I released my apps it's displayed in the search result.